# ftp command not found only on shell script

Tags: linux, shell, ftp

I'm trying to use FTP on shell script to put a file from one server to other one. Following the code

```
HOST='206.35.8.213'
USER='my_username'
PASSWD='_mypassword'
FILE='mydata.log'
PATH='/export/home/oracle/europa/'



ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
user $USER $PASSWD
cd $PATH
put $FILE
bye
EOF
```

this is throwing the error as follows

> ./ftp.sh: line 9: ftp: command not found

Here the FTP available on the server. Could any one help on identifying the issue.

Comment: Why this is suggested for off topic. Isn't the shell script coming under programming topic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've over written the `PATH` variable which is used to search for binaries. What you've effectively told the shell is that the `ftp` binary will be in `/export/home/oracle/europa/`. Change your variable name to something else.

As a rule, bash uses upper case for it's variables, see [Shell Variables in the bash manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash). I'd recommend using a different naming convention for your own variables. If you had named `PATH`, `path` `exportDir` or similar you wouldn't have had any problems.

Answer (score 0):

The package for FTP server is `vsftpd` , but for ftp client it is `ftp` . 
You need to install `ftp` service to start ftp sessions.